# Check individual items from a list of Valuetuple in c# 7

Tags: .net, list, types, valuetuple, c#-7.3

Please consider the following list of ValueTuple C#7

```
List<(double prices, int matches)> myList = new List<(double, int)>();

                    myList.Add((100, 9));  

                    myList.Add((100.50 , 12));
```

I can do Foreach var i in myList, myList.Max, myList.Average etc and it will return both types of the ValueTuple.

But, how can I check and return only the values for prices and/or matches? Can you post examples please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern-matching can be used to deconstruct the tuple in a for-each statement

```
List<(double prices, int matches)> myList = new List<(double, int)>();
myList.Add((100, 9));
myList.Add((100.50, 12));

foreach (var (price, match) in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Price: {price}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Match: {match}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `Select(x => x.prices)`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<(double prices, int matches)> myList = new List<(double, int)>();
    myList.Add((100, 9));
    myList.Add((100.50, 12));

    var prices = myList.Select(x => x.prices);
    var matches = myList.Select(x => x.matches);

    Console.WriteLine("prices:");
    foreach (var item in prices)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

    Console.WriteLine("\nmatches:");
    foreach (var item in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(item);

    Console.Read();
}
```

**Output:**

```
prices:
100
100.5

matches:
9
12
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! Simple and powerful!!

Comment: And how can this be done if instead of returning "prices" and "matches" in a IEnumerable, these are returned inside a new List? Is that possible to do it direct or it needs the Select to return the values as IEnumerable and then add them to a List ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach:

```
var _someCollection = new List<(int Id, string Name)> { (123, "abc") };
...
_someCollection.ForEach(_ => {
   _.Id = 1;
   _.Name = "a";
});
```

In this case you do not need to redefine names as needed in simple foreach statement, which can lead to bugs and harder to debug code if renamed differently.